# Set partition with constraints in Python

Tags: python, constraints, partition

I had a hard time to deal with a group partition issue. Will someone shed 
some light for me please?

Let me simplify my question. I want to divide ten numbers (i.e., `0, 1, ..., 9`) 
into three groups, with (`4, 3, 3`) numbers each group. The conditions are:

1. Within-group sequence dones't matter. For example, [(`0, 1, 2, 3`), (`4, 5,
   6`), (`7, 8, 9`)] will be treated to be the same as [(`3, 0, 1, 2`),
   (`5, 6, 4`), (`7, 8, 9`)].
2. I want to keep (`1, 2, 3`) always in the same group, and so does for (`7, 8`).

How can I list all the possible grouping scenarios which meet the above criteria? Thanks a lot!

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Your requirements for 2. are unclear. What determines what numbers should always be in the same group?

Comment: When you ignore the order within sets, it's not all permutations, it's all set partitions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Comment: @DTing: I set up the constraints arbitrarily.

Comment: @PeterAdam then you have to generate all partitions and filter them with your conditions

Comment: @EvenLisie: Thanks. I have changed the title from permutation to set partition.

Comment: this is more a math question than a coding one.

Comment: Is `[{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6}{7,8,9}]` different from `[{0,1,2,3},{7,8,9},{4,5,6}]`?

Comment: @gboffi: they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to partition in 3 blocks of size 4,3,3, with (1,2,3) in one block and (7,8) in one block.

That means that 1,2,3 and 7,8 cannot be in same block.

Let first forget the keyboard and analyse the problem

IMHO, you should separate 3 cases :

- 1,2,3 are in block of size 4 (case 1)
- 7,8 are in block of size 4 (case 2)
- neither 1,2,3 nor 7,8 and in block of size 4 (case 3)

### Case 1

- one element from (0,4,5,6,9) goes in block containing (1, 2, 3)
- one other element from (0,4,5,6,9) goes in block containing (7,8)

total : 5*4 = 20 different partitions

### Case 2

- two elements from (0,4,5,6,9) go in block containing (7,8)

total : 5*4/2 = 10 different partitions (/2 because you want combinations and not permutations)

### Case 3

- one element from (0,4,5,6,9) goes in block containing (7,8)

total : 5 different partitions

So you know you shall have 35 different partitions

Python code :

```
def gen():
    B1 = [1,2,3]
    B2 = [7,8]
    C = [x for x in range(10) if x not in B1 + B2 ]
    def gen1():
        for x in C:
            c = C[:]
            b1 = B1[:]
            b1.append(x)
            c.remove(x)
            for y in c:
                c1 = c[:]
                b2 = B2[:]
                b2.append(y)
                c1.remove(y)
                yield(b1, b2, c1)
    def gen2():
        for i in range(len(C)-1):
            for j in range(i+1, len(C)):
                b2 = B2 + [C[i], C[j]]
                c = [C[k] for k in range(len(C)) if k not in (i,j)]
                yield (B1, b2, c)
    def gen3():
        for x in C:
            b2 = B2[:]
            c = C[:]
            c.remove(x)
            b2.append(x)
            yield(B1, b2, c)
    for g in (gen1, gen2, gen3):
        for t in g():
            yield t
```

And you get correctly :

```
>>> list(gen())
[([1, 2, 3, 0], [7, 8, 4], [5, 6, 9]), ([1, 2, 3, 0], [7, 8, 5], [4, 6, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 0], [7, 8, 6], [4, 5, 9]), ([1, 2, 3, 0], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 0], [5, 6, 9]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 5], [0, 6, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 6], [0, 5, 9]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9], [0, 5, 6]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 5], [7, 8, 0], [4, 6, 9]), ([1, 2, 3, 5], [7, 8, 4], [0, 6, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 5], [7, 8, 6], [0, 4, 9]), ([1, 2, 3, 5], [7, 8, 9], [0, 4, 6]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 6], [7, 8, 0], [4, 5, 9]), ([1, 2, 3, 6], [7, 8, 4], [0, 5, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 6], [7, 8, 5], [0, 4, 9]), ([1, 2, 3, 6], [7, 8, 9], [0, 4, 5]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 9], [7, 8, 0], [4, 5, 6]), ([1, 2, 3, 9], [7, 8, 4], [0, 5, 6]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 9], [7, 8, 5], [0, 4, 6]), ([1, 2, 3, 9], [7, 8, 6], [0, 4, 5]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 0, 4], [5, 6, 9]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 0, 5], [4, 6, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 0, 6], [4, 5, 9]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 0, 9], [4, 5, 6]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 4, 5], [0, 6, 9]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 4, 6], [0, 5, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 4, 9], [0, 5, 6]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 5, 6], [0, 4, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 5, 9], [0, 4, 6]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 6, 9], [0, 4, 5]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 0], [4, 5, 6, 9]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 4], [0, 5, 6, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 5], [0, 4, 6, 9]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 6], [0, 4, 5, 9]),
 ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [0, 4, 5, 6])]
```

(manual formatting to ease reading ...)

Answer (score 2):

```
For comb in combination k=3 in (0,4,5,6,9), remaining a, b:
(g1+a, g2+b, comb)    (g1+b, g2+a, comb)
(g2+a+b, g3, g1)

For comb in combination k=4 in (0,4,5,6,9), remaining a:
(comb, g1, g2+a)
```

---

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

def partition_generator():
  wildcards = (0,4,5,6,9)
  g1, g2 = (1,2,3), (7,8)
  for comb in combinations(wildcards, 3):
    unused = remaining(wildcards, comb)
    for r in permutations(unused):
      yield part(g1, g2, comb, r)
    yield part(g2, g1, comb, unused)
  for comb in combinations(wildcards, 4):
    yield part(comb, g1, g2, remaining(wildcards, comb))

def remaining(a, b):
  return [ x for x in a if x not in b ]

def part(x,y,z,remaining):
  q = list(remaining)
  while len(x) < 4:
    x = x + (q.pop(0),)
  if len(y) < 3:
    y = y + (q.pop(0),)
  if len(z) < 3:
    z = z + (q.pop(0),)
  return (x,y,z)
```

```js
>>> for partition in partition_generator():
...   print(partition)
...
((1, 2, 3, 6), (7, 8, 9), (0, 4, 5))
((1, 2, 3, 9), (7, 8, 6), (0, 4, 5))
((7, 8, 6, 9), (1, 2, 3), (0, 4, 5))
((1, 2, 3, 5), (7, 8, 9), (0, 4, 6))
((1, 2, 3, 9), (7, 8, 5), (0, 4, 6))
((7, 8, 5, 9), (1, 2, 3), (0, 4, 6))
((1, 2, 3, 5), (7, 8, 6), (0, 4, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 6), (7, 8, 5), (0, 4, 9))
((7, 8, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3), (0, 4, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 4), (7, 8, 9), (0, 5, 6))
((1, 2, 3, 9), (7, 8, 4), (0, 5, 6))
((7, 8, 4, 9), (1, 2, 3), (0, 5, 6))
((1, 2, 3, 4), (7, 8, 6), (0, 5, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 6), (7, 8, 4), (0, 5, 9))
((7, 8, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3), (0, 5, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 4), (7, 8, 5), (0, 6, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 5), (7, 8, 4), (0, 6, 9))
((7, 8, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3), (0, 6, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 0), (7, 8, 9), (4, 5, 6))
((1, 2, 3, 9), (7, 8, 0), (4, 5, 6))
((7, 8, 0, 9), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
((1, 2, 3, 0), (7, 8, 6), (4, 5, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 6), (7, 8, 0), (4, 5, 9))
((7, 8, 0, 6), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 0), (7, 8, 5), (4, 6, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 5), (7, 8, 0), (4, 6, 9))
((7, 8, 0, 5), (1, 2, 3), (4, 6, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 0), (7, 8, 4), (5, 6, 9))
((1, 2, 3, 4), (7, 8, 0), (5, 6, 9))
((7, 8, 0, 4), (1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 9))
((0, 4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9))
((0, 4, 5, 9), (1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 6))
((0, 4, 6, 9), (1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 5))
((0, 5, 6, 9), (1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 4))
((4, 5, 6, 9), (1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem correctly, this should do what you requested:

```
from copy import deepcopy

# slice into appropriate chunks
def slice_lst(size_tup, lst):
  for index, length in enumerate(size_tup):
    running_total = sum(size_tup[:index])
    yield lst[running_total:running_total+length]

# perform integer partition
def integer_partition(num):
  return {(x,) + y for x in range(1, num) for y in integer_partition(num-x)} | {(num,)}

# create all partitions given the starting list
def subsets(lst):
  for partition in integer_partition(len(lst)):
    yield list(slice_lst(partition, deepcopy(lst)))

# check that 1,2 and 3 are always contained within the same subset
def triplet_case(lst):
  bool_arr = [1 in lst, 2 in lst, 3 in lst]
  return all(bool_arr) or not any (bool_arr)

# check that 7 and 8 are always contained within the same subset
def duplet_case(lst):
  bool_arr = [7 in lst, 8 in lst]
  return all(bool_arr) or not any(bool_arr)

for subset in subsets([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]):
  if all([triplet_case(s) for s in subset]) and all([duplet_case(s) for s in subset]):
    print subset
```

Feel free to ask follow-up questions if you have any!

Comment: Thanks EvenLisle. This is a bit different from what I intended. First, I need three groups with size = 4, 3, 3. Second, your code seems only group the neighboring numbers. For example, number 9 will never stay with 1,2,3 in one group.